# How to fix this error: unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting do or '{' or '('

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, syntax-error

I am currently getting an error when I try to open the view home, which contains the following code:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session, method :delete%>
```

> Error: 1: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting do or '{' or '(' ... destroy_user_session, method :delete);@output_buffer.safe_a... ... ^

What would be the correct syntax and what causes this error in my case?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot colon (`:`) in `{ method: :delete }` hash literal:

```
<%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session, method: :delete %>
```